# Apache enable worker mpm

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I have configured FastCGI and PHP5-FPM to work on ubuntu, Which is working fine.

But i installed **"apache2 worker mpm"** module and wanted to configure and replace **"prefork mpm"** which is default in apache2.

All i found was in CentOS at `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` just putting `HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker` will make **"worker mpm"** enabled.

1. How do we enable "worker mpm" in Ubuntu?
2. Also when i list the compiled modules of apache `"/usr/sbin/apachectl -l"` it wont list `"prefork.c"` which said to be listing since we are using it by default. But when i do `"/usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep MPM"` it shows **"Server MPM: prefork"** can some one explain this please?

$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep MPM

```
Server MPM:     prefork
```

phpinfo();

```
Server API :    FPM/FastCGI
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After some time of working i did it myself. You can find the steps below.

Check which MPM apache is currently running:

```
apachectl -V | grep -i mpm

Result:
Server MPM:     prefork
```

List Available MPM Modules (Make sure mpm_worker is listed)

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm*

Result:
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.conf  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_event.load  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.load  /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_worker.load
```

List Enabled MPM Modules (If mpm_worker is not enabled we should enable it and disable the mpm_prefork module)

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm*

Result:
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf -> ../mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.load -> ../mods-available/mpm_prefork.load
```

Disable MPM_PREFORK module

```
a2dismod mpm_prefork
```

Enable MPM_WORKER module

```
a2enmod mpm_worker
```

To check if Apache is running on MPM WORKER

```
apachectl -V | grep -i mpm

Result:
Server MPM:     worker
```

If you get this error after executing these commands:

```
Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP
```

Try to remove libapache2 package:

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: Followed the instruction but getting this:
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                      [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: perfect :) it's working for me.

Comment: It is giving error "Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP" and removing libapache2-mod-php5 is not helping either.

Answer (score 2):

Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error after executing these commands:

```
Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP
```

Try to remove libapache2 package:

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php7.0
```