# Apache with Worker MPM giving error - your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP

Tags: apache2, php, php-fpm

I am having Ubuntu 14.10 and Apache 2.4. Currently Apache is running default `mpm_prefork` and I want to change it to `mpm_worker`.

I followed this [Apache enable worker mpm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524770/apache-enable-worker-mpm) to disable `mpm_prefork` and enable `mpm_worker` but when I am restarting Apache, it is giving error:

```
Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
```

Now this is because PHP 5 doesn't work with `mpm_worker` so, I followed this [How to configure Apache to run PHP as FastCGI on Ubuntu 12.04 via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378734/how-to-configure-apache-to-run-php-as-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-via-terminal/527227#527227) and now I am running `fastcgi` as shown in `phpinfo()`.

[image: phpinfo]

Everything looks fine but again, when I am disabling `mpm_prefork` and enabling `mpm_worker`, I am getting this error:

```
Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
```

So I have have to go to default `mpm_prefork` module to keep the site running. I am not sure what else to be done, any help ?

Comment: For thorough discussion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623914/what-is-thread-safe-or-non-thread-safe-in-php. As you are using FastCGI, you should disable `mod_php`, so it is not loaded by apache.

Comment: @ridgy - I ran a2dismod php5 and it is shwoing "Module php5 already disabled". I have also ran apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5 still not able to run mpm_worker as it is giving same error.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in the apache configuration tree some php module is loaded (different from that installed `by apt-get`?) try `cd /etc/apache2; . envvar; apache2 -D DUMP_MODULES -t`

Comment: Thanks, I figured out. There php5filter mod enabled. Once I disabled it, I was able to move to worker from prefork.